# Linear System O.D.E.: 1<dim(Eigenspace)<eigenvalue multiplicity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Let’s be:

- the linear system $\boldsymbol{x}’=A\boldsymbol{x}$ where $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is constant and
- an eigenvalue ($\lambda$) with multiplicity $m>1$.

What happens if the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has dimension $k$, where $1<k<m$? If we have $k$ ($1<k<m$) linearly independent eigenvectors ($\boldsymbol{u_1},\dots,\boldsymbol{u_k}$), how can I construct $m$ inependent solutions of the O.D.E. $\boldsymbol{x}’=A\boldsymbol{x}$?

I know what to do:

- if $k=1$ (make a chain with generalized eigenvectors starting from the $\boldsymbol{u_1}$ eigenvector [e.t.c.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810897/system-of-3-variable-differential-equations-with-3-repeating-eigen-values/2810935#2810935)),
- if $k=m$ (make $m$ independent solutions $\boldsymbol{u_1}e^{\lambda t},\dots,\boldsymbol{u_m}e^{\lambda t}$.

I don't know what to do if $1<k<m$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with Jordan forms?

Comment: No. I hoped that there will be an easy way, like the cases $k=1$ or $k=m$.